# Show notification message after ajax call

Tags: magento2, frontend, ajax, notification

I have my own controller for a `customer address` delete, so at the end of the controller, I send a notification message to notify the user.

```
 try{

        $this->_addressRepository->deleteById($addressId);
        return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => true,'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccess("Successfully deleted customer address")]);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

        return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => false,'message' => $this->messageManager->addError('Address cannot be deleted')]);

    }
```

and at the `success` of ajax call I reload the page and after reloading the message should display on the UI.

```
 success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
```

But the issue is `notification message` is displayed before the reload, and after the reload the message stays(which I want).

The issue is the message gets displayed as soon as i do this

```
return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => true,'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccess("Successfully deleted customer address")])
```

I want to show the message after reloading the page, how can I achieve that